# xamarin iphone app crashes on end user's devices

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I completed the development of application and pushed to appstore. I don't know the solution and even don't know why app crashes on end user's devices.
I am able to get the crash logs and here is the logs. Please help me to resolve this unknown crash.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,4
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183ea1014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6b264 pthread_kill + 112 (pthread.c:1366)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183e159c4 abort + 140 (abort.c:91)
3   Mono                            0x00000001058702cc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 588
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000183f6531c _sigtramp + 52 (sigtramp.c:115)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6b264 pthread_kill + 112 (pthread.c:1366)
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183e159c4 abort + 140 (abort.c:91)
7   MyApp                           0x000000010018dd0c print_all_exceptions(MonoObject*) (runtime.m:997)
8   Mono                            0x0000000105870a14 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 100
9   Mono                            0x000000010586fca8 mono_handle_exception_internal + 3860
10  Mono                            0x000000010586ed88 mono_handle_exception + 40
11  Mono                            0x0000000105866424 handle_signal_exception + 64
12  MyApp                           0x000000010023cb04 MyApp_MyApp_iOS_UpdatePostCommentsViewController__ViewDidLoadm__1_object_System_EventArgs + 276
13  MyApp                           0x0000000100cd1bc8 Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIControlEventProxy_Activated (UIControl.cs:37)
14  MyApp                           0x0000000100fe5c54 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
15  Mono                            0x000000010587e654 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1772
16  Mono                            0x00000001058eecf0 do_runtime_invoke + 112
17  Mono                            0x00000001058eec4c mono_runtime_invoke + 208
18  MyApp                           0x0000000101904980 native_to_managed_trampoline_9(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, char const*, char const*) (registrar.m:385)
19  MyApp                           0x0000000101905a50 -[UIKit_UIControlEventProxy BridgeSelector] (registrar.m:10469)
20  UIKit                           0x000000018b00d010 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96 (UIApplication.m:4580)
21  UIKit                           0x000000018b00cf90 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80 (UIControl.m:609)
22  UIKit                           0x000000018aff7504 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440 (UIControl.m:694)
23  UIKit                           0x000000018b00c874 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 576 (UIControl.m:446)
24  UIKit                           0x000000018b00c390 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2480 (UIWindow.m:2122)
25  UIKit                           0x000000018b007728 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3192 (UIWindow.m:2292)
26  UIKit                           0x000000018afd833c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340 (UIApplication.m:10778)
27  UIKit                           0x000000018b7d2014 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2400 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1448)
28  UIKit                           0x000000018b7cc770 __handleEventQueue + 4268 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1671)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e5542c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1943)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e54d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540 (CFRunLoop.c:1989)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e529a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744 (CFRunLoop.c:2821)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d82da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
33  GraphicsServices                0x00000001867ec074 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
34  UIKit                           0x000000018b03d058 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4089)
35  MyApp                           0x0000000100d74914 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr (/<unknown>:1)
36  MyApp                           0x0000000100ccf6c8 Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:63)
37  MyApp                           0x000000010035c9a8 MyApp_MyApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 196
38  MyApp                           0x0000000100fe5c54 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
39  Mono                            0x000000010587e654 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1772
40  Mono                            0x00000001058eecf0 do_runtime_invoke + 112
41  Mono                            0x00000001058f12d4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 832
42  Mono                            0x00000001058f0ef0 mono_runtime_run_main + 764
43  Mono                            0x0000000105862c48 mono_jit_exec + 236
44  MyApp                           0x000000010019a6cc xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:487)
45  MyApp                           0x000000010199c3d0 main (main.arm64.m:115)
46  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000183d9159c start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183ea0e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f68814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640 (pthread_cond.c:536)
2   Mono                            0x000000010594d854 thread_func + 356
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6968c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6959c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f66cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183e83260 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   Mono                            0x00000001058b179c finalizer_thread + 200
2   Mono                            0x0000000105921974 start_wrapper + 512
3   Mono                            0x000000010595a28c inner_start_thread + 360
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6968c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6959c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f66cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183e83224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183e8309c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e54e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e52ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d82da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   Foundation                      0x000000018589cd74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001858bdb44 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b9c76a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:313)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018599a2d8 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1163)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6968c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6959c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f66cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183ea0e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f68814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640 (pthread_cond.c:536)
2   Mono                            0x00000001058260d0 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 168
3   Mono                            0x0000000105825dc8 _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle + 452
4   Mono                            0x000000010596c55c wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx + 632
5   Mono                            0x000000010591d078 mono_wait_uninterrupted + 148
6   Mono                            0x000000010591d308 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal + 108
7   MyApp                           0x0000000100f7af28 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_internal_intptr_int + 104
8   MyApp                           0x0000000100e8392c mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOneNative_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_uint_bool_bool (WaitHandle.cs:102)
9   MyApp                           0x0000000100e837e0 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_InternalWaitOne_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_long_bool_bool (waithandle.cs:257)
10  MyApp                           0x0000000100e83714 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int_bool (waithandle.cs:239)
11  MyApp                           0x0000000100e83790 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int (waithandle.cs:1)
12  MyApp                           0x0000000100ec414c mscorlib_System_Threading_Timer_Scheduler_SchedulerThread (Timer.cs:395)
13  MyApp                           0x0000000100e8194c mscorlib_System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart_Context_object (thread.cs:72)
14  MyApp                           0x0000000100e80558 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool (executioncontext.cs:957)
15  MyApp                           0x0000000100e802fc mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object (executioncontext.cs:893)
16  MyApp                           0x0000000100e81a5c mscorlib_System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart (thread.cs:109)
17  MyApp                           0x0000000100fe5c54 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
18  Mono                            0x000000010587e654 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1772
19  Mono                            0x00000001058eecf0 do_runtime_invoke + 112
20  Mono                            0x00000001059219f0 start_wrapper + 636
21  Mono                            0x000000010595a28c inner_start_thread + 360
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6968c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6959c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f66cb4 thread_start + 4


Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183ea0e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f68814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640 (pthread_cond.c:536)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000183891ac8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56 (condition_variable.cpp:44)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189735f94 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 112 (condition_variable:202)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189735f08 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 168 (condition_variable:211)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189735de8 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*) + 36 (AsyncTask.h:110)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000189736098 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92 (__functional_base:416)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6968c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6959c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f66cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183e83224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183e8309c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e54e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184e52ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d82da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   WebCore                         0x0000000189a54608 RunWebThread(void*) + 456 (WebCoreThread.mm:694)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6968c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f6959c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183f66cb4 thread_start + 4


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000000000001b
    x4: 0x000000000000001b   x5: 0x000000016fd7e450   x6: 0x0000000000000031   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000003dd5  x11: 0x00000001ad78dc43
   x12: 0x00000001ad78dc43  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001ab008b40  x21: 0x0000000105979cec  x22: 0x0000000105979db3  x23: 0xbcbc681ea5d30086
   x24: 0x000000016fd7e888  x25: 0x0000000105979d66  x26: 0x0000000123408f60  x27: 0x0000000105ea6d98
   x28: 0x0000000105c01dc0   fp: 0x000000016fd7e820   lr: 0x0000000183f6b264
    sp: 0x000000016fd7e800   pc: 0x0000000183ea1014 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x10007c000 - 0x101a2ffff MyApp arm64  <2e4e02b1232a35f3a699732f3690815a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/05168991-54CE-41A2-833F-14F645E2B8AD/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x105790000 - 0x1057c3fff dyld arm64  <a3339f99c2ea39d8beb70b8ff2e84061> /usr/lib/dyld
0x105818000 - 0x1059f3fff Mono arm64  <4d8383ffb7633ede9023910f4e550a9b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/05168991-54CE-41A2-833F-14F645E2B8AD/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono
0x183888000 - 0x183889fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  

EOF
```

Comment: It seems like your crash originated here: `UIApplication.cs:63`.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez : sorry, please help me in detail. I didn't get you by UIApplication.cs:63. I understand it means line 63 hope so, but what is UIApplication class pointing to.

Comment: UIApplication class is a system class, it does not initiate a crash. From this crash log is hard to say, but my suggestion is you try to update UI from non-UI thread.

Comment: What's your linking behavior ?

Comment: My bad, my brain parsed that as `ApplicationDelegate.cs` since I expected the offending code to be in a `C#` file and that was the only one. You might have better luck in a Xamarin-only forum. The only other clue I see in that crash log is `MyApp_MyApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 196`, but I'm not sure what exactly that translates to.

Comment: @Krishna : I tried all 3 linking options.